# Atiyah-Macdonald: Exercise 3.5

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, localization, nilpotence

Let $A$ be a ring. Suppose that, for each prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$, the local ring $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ has no nilpotent elements $\neq 0$. Show that $A$ has no nilpotent element $\neq 0$. If each $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is an integral domain, is $A$ necessarily an integral domain?

---

I have found an answer to the second question. Consider $A=\mathbb{Z_{4}}$, the only prime ideal of $A$ is $\{\bar{0},\bar{2}\}$ then for $S:=A\setminus\mathfrak{p}$ we have $S^{-1}A=\{\frac{0}{1},\frac{1}{1},\frac{2}{1},\frac{1}{3}\}$ which is an integral domain, but $A$ is not. **(The property of being Integral Domain is not local.)**

For the first part, I tried to proceed as follows: Let there exist $(0\neq)a \in A$ such that $a^n=0$, again $1 \in S$ $\implies$ $\frac{a}{1} \in S^{-1}A$ such that $(\frac{a}{1})^n=\frac{a^n}{1}=\frac{0}{1}$. To arrive at a contradiction it remains to show that $\frac{a}{1}\neq 0.$ If $\frac{a}{1}=\frac{0}{1}$ then there exist $t \in A\setminus \mathfrak{p}$ such that $ta=0$.

I cannot think of any way out from here. Please help.

Is the converse true? **(i.e Is "the existence of a nonzero nilpotent element in $A$" a local property?)**

Comment: Your answer to the second question doesn't work. $1$ and $3$ are already units in $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, so localizing at $S = \{1, 3\}$ doesn't change anything: $S^{-1} A \cong \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. You can also see why this couldn't work from the first part. $2$ is nilpotent in $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, so if $S^{-1} A$ were an integral domain, then it has no nilpotents, so $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ has no nilpotents by the first part, contradiction. Try looking at $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy)$ instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track, and you're correct that you're done if you can show $\frac{a}{1}\ne 0,$ i.e. there is no $t\in A\setminus\mathfrak p$ such that $ta=0.$ But keep in mind you only need to find one prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ for which this holds. So you can take $\mathfrak p$ to be a maximal extension of the ideal $\{b\in A: ba=0\}.$

Comment: Ok. That means taking $\mathfrak{p}$ to be a maximal extension of $\{b \in A: ba=0\}$ there does not exist any $t \in A \setminus \mathfrak{p}$ such that $ta=0$. (as all such t are in $\mathfrak{p}$) $\implies \frac{a}{1} \neq 0 \ \text{in} \ A_{\mathfrak{p}}$. Am I correct?

Comment: @Saikat Yes, that’s right.

Comment: Is the converse true?

Comment: @Saikat Yes, let $(x/s)^n=0$ in $S^{-1}A$ for $x/s\ne 0.$ Then there is a $t\in S$ such that $x^nt=0,$ and so $xt$ is a nonzero element of $A$ with $(xt)^n=0.$

Comment: @Saikat By the way, there is a "slicker" solution to both directions at once: Use the fact that the nilradical of the localization is the localization of the nilradical combined with the fact that being zero is a local property.

Comment: Ok, you mean to say $Nil(A_{\mathfrak{p}})=S^{-1}Nil(A)$? Where $S=A \setminus \mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: @Saikat Yes, that's right.